# SystemVerilog: implies operator vs. |->

Tags: system-verilog, system-verilog-assertions, implication

Recently the question came up what the difference is between the usual implication operator (`|->`) and the `implies` operator in SystemVerilog. Unfortunately I couldn't find a clear answer yet. However, I collected the following information:

**From [SystemVerilog LRM 1800-2012](http://standards.ieee.org/getieee/1800/download/1800-2012.pdf):**

- § 16.12.7 *Implies and iff properties*:

  > `property_expr1 implies property_expr2`
  > A property of this form evaluates to true if, and only if, either property_expr1 evaluates to false or property_expr2 evaluates to true.
- § F.3.4.3.2 *Derived Boolean operators*:

  > `p1 implies p2 ≡ (not p1 or p2)`
- § F.3.4.3.4 *Derived conditional operators*:

  > `(if(b) P) ≡ (b |-> P)`

However, the LRM does not really point out what the actual difference is. I assume that they differ in the evaluation in case of a false antecedent (success vs. vacuous success), but I could not find any source or evidence for this assumption. Moreover, I know that the `implies` operator is very common in combination with formal verification tools like OneSpin.

Could anyone help me out?

P.S.: It seems there is an answer to this question in the following book: *SystemVerilog Assertions Handbook, 3rd Edition*. But $155 is a bit too much for me just for getting the answer to this question :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think there is even a more significant difference. Assume that we have the following example:

```
property p1;
  @ (posedge clk) 
  a ##1 b |-> c;
endproperty

property p2;
  @ (posedge clk) 
  a ##1 b implies c;
endproperty

assert property (p1);
assert property (p2);
```

Both implication operators simply have different proving behavior. Property `p1` will be triggered through a match of `a ##1 b` and will look for a matching `c` during the same clock tick as `b`. However, property `p2` is triggered by `a ##1 b` and will check for a match of `c` during the clock cycle of `a`. This means the properties would pass for the following scenarios:

Property p1 passes and p2 fails:
[image: Property p1 passes and p2 fails]
Property p2 passes and p1 fails:
[image: Property p2 passes and p1 fails]

A hint for this behavior can be found in the SystemVerilog LRM. The defined substitutions are:

```
(if(b) P) = (b |-> P)
p1 implies p2 = (not p1 or p2)
```

So all in all, if one uses the implies operator it becomes easier to define multi-cycle operations since antecedent and consequence have the same starting point for the evaluation.

Comment: Tried it out on a different simulator and it behaves the same. It seems like you're right.

Comment: @sebs in both waveforms, signals a,b and c are changing at the posedge of clk. This makes it confusing to see which value is being sampled at the posedge of clk.  From your explanation, the new value is being sampled while from my understanding, the value prior to the posedge of the clk should be sampled for assertion evaluation. Please clarify

Answer (score 2):

I tried it out and apparently the `|->` is not allowed for properties (only for sequences and boolean expressions). Here's what I tried:

```
  property a_and_b;
    @(posedge clk)
    a && b;
  endproperty

  property a_and_c;
    @(posedge clk)
    a && c;
  endproperty
```

First form using `|->` doesn't compile:

```
// this doesn't compile
assert property(a_and_b |-> a_and_c);
```

Second form using `implies` does compile:

```
// this does compile
assert property(a_and_b implies a_and_c);
```

Semantic-wise, it's as it is for the `|->` operator. When `a_and_b` fails, the assertion vacuously passes. If `a_and_b` succeeds but `b_and_c` doesn't, then a fail is issued.

Comment: I think you've used the properties in an improper way. Instead of using property definitions for both a_and_b and a_and_c and combining them to a new property you should have used sequence definitions. After doing so both examples should compile. Which simulator did you use?

I used the following example to simulate with Incisive:
First property: a |-> b
Second property: a implies b

When simulating a design with these properties there is no difference between both results. When signal a goes low both properties become inactive. So no success or vacuous success.

Comment: Agreed that if you use sequences it will compile with both operators, but you were asking about using the operators with properties. Those are just some crazy properties that I made up to try it out. You're not seeing the forest because of the trees if you're concentrating on how those properties could be rewritten.